# How to prevent remount when going back a page in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have routes which are lists of products:

/best-products

/new-products

...

Then I have a route when the user clicks on a specific product in the list:

/product/:id

My problem is I don't want to remount the previous component when the user go back.

For example:

1. The user is in /best-products (using filters and changing pages)
2. User clicks on product
3. User go back -> everything remounts

How can I prevent a remount when I go back, so that the user keeps his filters, data, etc?

Thanks for the help

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={"/"} exact component={Home} />
        <Route path={"/product/:id"} exact component={ProductPage}/>
        <Route path={"/best-products"} exact component={BestProducts}/>
        <Route path={"/new-products"} exact component={NewProducts}/>
        ... (more lists of products)
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: you can use  `target="_blank"` in your anchor tag. It will open your page in new tab and you can avoid your component getting unmount at first place. Other way around is to save all the necessary states in redux store or in some parent component that lie outside Router, pass them to routes and manage them accordingly.

Comment: ok thanks. I'm surprised there isn't an easy way for this like react-navigation for react native.

Comment: A third option is to put the selected filter values in the URL query string